# I like this trick...but is it safe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

The main issue I'm thinking about is whether assigning a variable in an if statement is safe and reliable across different browsers. If it is safe, I'd like to use it.

Here it reads the querystring and if the querystring variable SN is either Twitter or Facebook then it enters the if and you can use the variable, if the querystring variable doesn't exist or is some other value then it goes into the else.

```
    if(socialNetwork = (window.location.search.indexOf("SN=Twitter") > 0) ? "Twitter" : ((window.location.search.indexOf("SN=Facebook") > 0) ? "Facebook" : null))
    {
        alert(socialNetwork);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("nope");
    }
```

Comment: To be blunt, that code is god-awful to read and regardless of safety in javascript you should not ever do that, for the sake of other people who might want to read your code in the future. One John Resig is enough for this world.

Comment: @Marc I thought John was pretty conservative, style-wise; read the jQuery style guide sometime. Maybe you know something I don't :-)

Comment: I completely agree with Marc W. Regardless of whether that works, make your code easier to understand. I can look at that line for a moment and not know what it does.

Comment: Yo dawg, I herd you like conditionals, so I put conditionals in your conditionals so you can confuse programmers while you confuse programmers!

Comment: @Pointy The following horror can be found in the source code at http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.2/ui/ui.draggable.js:

if(!((l-d x1 && x1 r+d && t-d y1 && y1 b+d) || (l-d x1 && x1 r+d && t-d y2 && y2 b+d) || (l-d x2 && x2 r+d && t-d y1 && y1 b+d) || (l-d x2 && x2 r+d && t-d y2 && y2 b+d))) { ... }

Comment: So I'm getting a lot of "No"'s haha. My intention was to limit the number of lines of code for several reasons that I won't get into here. I realize it could be done a lot cleaner, I was just trying to see if it would work across browsers. But I'm probably focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: @Marc W At least he prefaces it with //Yes, I know, this is insane ;)

Comment: Is Mr. Resig responsible for the jQuery UI stuff too? I was under the impression that that stuff was collected from all sorts of places. (And I'm not the biggest fan of jQuery UI anyway, though I'm broadly happy that it exists.)

Comment: @Marc W and @Pointy this is not the work of John Resig, see http://dev.jqueryui.com/changeset/126/trunk/ui/source/ui.draggable.js

Comment: @strager First SO comment that ever made me laugh out loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's ugly.

```
var uselessSocialNetworkingApp = window.location.search.replace(/.*\bSN=(\w+)\b.*/, "$1");
if (uselessSocialNetworkingApp)
  alert("yay!");
else
  alert("no");
```

It's kind-of funny that there'd be that hideous construction in the "if" header, but that it'd be an "if" instead of a "? :" expression inside the "alert" argument list :-)

Also, to be at least slightly sympathetic to the intended style, this is an example of what the "let" statement in ultra-modern Javascript is for.

Answer (score 5):

It is part of the language design and should work in every browser, but it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my! This is valid and should always work, assuming that you create the socialNetwork variable elsewhere, don't ever create implied globals. However, this is really a strange way to solve your problem. Why not create a function that returns the social network to abstract this a little?

That said, if you really want a one line solution, how about this?:

```
alert(function(){ var m = /SN=([A-Za-z]+)/.exec(window.location.search); return (m ? m[1] : null)}());
```

Comment: Well it does cut down excess characters being sent over the internet by like 5 bytes. For production, I think it is perfectly fine, but for development I would suggest proper coding

Answer (score 0):

```
location.socialNetwork== (function(){
 var s= location.search || '';
 s= /SN=([a-zA-Z]+)/.exec(s) || [];
 return s[1] || null;

})()

alert(location.socialNetwork)
```